# Django form in every row of a table

Tags: ajax, django, forms, django-forms, formset

I want to have a simple text form on every row of a table.

Fiddle illustration of expected result: https://jsfiddle.net/wstg759f/1/

My `Models.py`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Quality(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    person=models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I have a queryset that returns aggregated list of all persons, count of qualities for each person, one random quality of this person:

```
[
{'the_count': 5, u'randomquality': u'Nice’, u'person__name': u'Joe'}, 
{'the_count': 4, u'randomquality': u'Generous’,u'person__name': u'Mike'}, 
{'the_count': 4, u'randomquality': u'Healthy’,u'person__name': u'John’'}, 
..
]
```

My view.html (qualities is my queryset)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Qualities count</th>
            <th>One random quality</th>
            <th>Add a Quality?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {%for obj in qualities%}
    <tr>
            <td>{{ obj.person__name }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.the_count  }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.randomquality  }}</td>
            <td>text form to submit a quality for this person</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The user should be able to input a quality in the text field, and once submitted it will be added to the model, and the text field is replaced by "thanks, submitted"
The submit form have to be independent.
I have no clear direction where to look at.
How would you do?

From my reading, I understand that formset could be a solution, but they are really unclear for me.
Should I even use django form in this case?
If yes, I believe the form should take an argument form the template: I don't need the user to tell me about the person name as it's already here.
Let me know if I can clarify.
Thanks in advance.

As a bonus, maybe for later, I want to avoid page refresh.
Is ajax the only way?

Comment: formsets work great for this, if you really want to submit all rows at the same time and reload the entire page. Your other option would be to implement this via AJAX calls, then you can simply submit only rows that have text (via a single button), or each row one at a time via a button on each or (or via onChange event in the text, depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish).

Comment: looked at your jsfiddle example...definatly a job of jQuery and AJAX calls.

Comment: It was more thinking about submitting them individually (each row one at a time via a button). If I use Jquery and ajax, do I still need formset? I also wanted to keep teh advantage of modelform for validation. Anyway, where should I start?

Comment: `FormSet` is really the thing you want, it's easy - just call `MyFormSet = formset_factory(MyForm)`, and then iterate through it in the template. Read through the relevant section in documentation, they have some nice examples which make it easy to understand

Comment: Checking. I just have a doubt: can the forms generated by formset be independent? (ie each row one at a time via a button on each)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with ajax, form and views

template.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Qualities count</th>
            <th>One random quality</th>
            <th>Add a Quality?</th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for obj in qualities %}
    <tr id="row_{{ obj.id }}">
            <td>{{ obj.person__name }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.the_count  }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.randomquality  }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.quality }}</td>
            <td><button value="{{ obj.id }}" onclick="addQuality(this.value)">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
    function addQuality(id_object) {
        const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value
        let data_to_backend = new FormData()
        let qualityToAdd = document.getElementById(`id_${id_object}-quality`).value
        if (qualityToAdd !== '') {
            data_to_backend.append('quality', qualityToAdd)
            data_to_backend.append('object_index', id_object)
        } else return
        const request = new Request("./", 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
            body: data_to_backend
        })
        fetch(request, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'same-origin'
        }).then(
            function(response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    let tableRow = document.getElementById(`row_${ id_object }`)
                    tableRow.innerHTML = "<p>thanks, submitted</p>"
                } else {
                    alert("Error")
                    console.log(response)
                }
            }
        )
    }
</script>
```

Set your views to receive a post request or just create a new urls path and another views

views.py

```
def addQuantity(request, codigo_orcamento):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = formAddQuantity(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            id_object = form.cleaned_data['object_index']
            quality = form.cleaned_data['quality']
            # get the object and add this quality
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=405)
```

In this view we simply check if the form is valid, get the object from db and add the quality on it

forms.py

```
class formAddQuantity(forms.Form):
    object_index = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    quality = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

A simple check, but i recommend you to add more requirements to this fields

(Not tested, if throws a error let me know)

Comment: Could you please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70371491/page-with-a-dynamic-number-of-forms-each-form-for-each-table-row) question? That's what I'm actually going to use.