# Page with a dynamic number of forms, each form for each table row

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-forms

The company has workers performing various activities during a day. Each activity has `start_time` and `finish_time`. It is usual that workers forget to beep the end of activity (`finish_time`) and that's because there is a stored procedure `read_unended time_from time_to` which reads records between `time_from` and `time_to` which has not `finish_time` (is `NULL`).
For example

```
id  name    day         start_time              finish_time place   activity
38  Thomas  2021-12-03  2021-12-03 08:51:38.000 NULL    p1  a1
28  Charles 2021-12-02  2021-12-02 12:29:03.000 NULL    p2  a2
49  John    2021-12-06  2021-12-06 11:59:48.000 NULL    p3  a3
68  Jessie  2021-12-08  2021-12-08 10:55:12.000 NULL    p4  a4
82  Susanne 2021-12-10  2021-12-10 12:38:03.000 NULL    p5  a5
```

There is a form in (`forms.py`)

```
class FromToForm(Form):
    start_date = DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())
    start_time = TimeField(widget=AdminTimeWidget())
    end_date = DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())
    end_time = TimeField(widget=AdminTimeWidget())
```

There is a view in (`views.py`) which displays such a table.

```
def ending(req):
    from_to_form = FromToForm()
    result = []
    context = {
                'form': from_to_form,
                'result': result
              }
    if req.method == "POST":
        from_to_form = FromToForm(req.POST)
        if from_to_form.is_valid():
            start = datetime.combine(from_to_form.cleaned_data['start_date'], from_to_form.cleaned_data['start_time']).isoformat()
            end = datetime.combine(from_to_form.cleaned_data['end_date'], from_to_form.cleaned_data['end_time']).isoformat()
            with connections["mssql_database"].cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("EXEC read_unended @dt_od='%s', @dt_do='%s'" % (start, end))
                result = cursor.fetchall()
            context['result'] = result
            return render(req, 'ending.html', context)
        else:
            return render(req, 'ending.html', context)
    else:
        return render(req, 'ending.html', context)
```

and an associated template in `templates.py`.

```
<form action='.' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.media }}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type='submit' value='Read unended' class="btn btn-secondary" />
        </form>
{% if result %}
        <table class="table mb-0">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>name</th>
                                <th>day</th>
                                <th>start_time</th>
                                <th>finish_time</th>
                                <th>place</th>
                                <th>activity</th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   {%for i in result %}
                     <tr>
                           <td>{{i.0}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.1}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.2}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.3}}</td>
                           <td>CELL TO INSERT END TIME*</td>
                           <td>{{i.5}}</td>
                           <td>{{i.6}}</td>
                           <td>BUTTON TO FINISH THIS ACTIVITY**<td/>
                     </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
        </table>
        {% else %}
           Every activity is ended
        {% endif %}
```

** and * is not implemented yet.
I'd like to implement the following functionality. In every row of the dynamically generated table, there should be a button ** to finish this activity (this row) with the time * the user of the application inserts. In that moment the page should refresh and that row should not be displayed anymore, because this activity has already `finish_time` assigned. How can I implement such a view and template? Do I need to add a dynamically generated fields to the existing form? What do you suggest?

Comment: Security alert: `cursor.execute("EXEC read_unended @dt_od='%s', @dt_do='%s'" % (start, end))` allows sql injections attacks.  Use this instead `cursor.execute("EXEC read_unended @dt_od='%s', @dt_do='%s'" ,(start, end))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a function to post your data and another to get the table body

template.html

```
     <table class="table mb-0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>day</th>
            <th>start_time</th>
            <th>finish_time</th>
            <th>place</th>
            <th>activity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyId">
        {% for i in result %}
        <tr>
            <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}0">{{i.0}}</td>
            <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}1">{{i.1}}</td>
            <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}2">{{i.2}}</td>
            <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}3">{{i.3}}</td>
            <td><input type="date" id="tdId_{{i.0}}4"/></td>
            <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}5">{{i.5}}</td>
            <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}6">{{i.6}}</td>
            <td><button value="{{i.0}}" type="button" onclick="setEndActivity(this.value)">End</button><td/>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function loadResults(activityId) {
    let xhttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const start_date = document.getElementById(`tdId_${activityId}2`).value
    const start_time = document.getElementById(`tdId_${activityId}3`).value
    const end_date = document.getElementById(`tdId_${activityId}2`).value
    const end_time = document.getElementById(`tdId_${activityId}4`).value
    xhttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("tbodyId").innerHTML = this.response
        }
    }
    xhttpRequest.open("GET", `./ajax/load-results?start_date=${start_date}&end_date=${end_date}&start_time=${start_time}&end_time=${end_time}`, true)
    xhttpRequest.send()
}

function setEndActivity(activityId) {
    const dataToBackEnd = new FormData()
    dataToBackEnd.append("activity", activityId)
    dataToBackEnd.append("start_date", document.getElementById(`tdId_${activityId}2`).value)
    dataToBackEnd.append("start_time", document.getElementById(`tdId_${activityId}3`).value)
    dataToBackEnd.append("end_date", document.getElementById(`tdId_${activityId}2`).value)
    dataToBackEnd.append("end_time", document.getElementById(`tdId_${activityId}4`).value)
    const request = new Request('./ajax/end-activity/',
    {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value },
        body: dataToBackEnd
    })
    fetch(request, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'same-origin'
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                loadResults(activityId)
            } else {
                alert("Error")
            }
        }
    )
}
</script>
```

In your views you will add 2 views, or just 1 if you modify the "ending" view to receive the post and return a http response

views.py

```
def ajax_ending(req):
    if req.method == "POST":
        from_to_form = FromToForm(req.POST)
        if from_to_form.is_valid():
            # save in database
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=405)


def ajax_load_results(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    if request.user:
        # get the activities
        start_date = request.GET['start_date']
        start_time = request.GET['start_time']
        start_date_time = f'{start_date} {start_time}'
        end_date = request.GET['end_date']
        end_time = request.GET['end_time']
        end_date_time = f'{end_date} {end_time}'
        # this datetime.strptime depends of how you write your date and time
        start = datetime.strptime(start_date_time, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S").isoformat()
        end = datetime.strptime(end_date_time, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S").isoformat()
        # i don't understand why you are executing queries like this, so i assume they work
        with connections["mssql_database"].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("EXEC read_unended @dt_od='%s', @dt_do='%s'" % (start, end))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
        context['result'] = result
        return render(request, 'ajax-ending.html', {"context": context})
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=403)
else:
    return HttpResponse(status=405)
```

And you will have another template.html just for tbody of table

ajax-ending.html

```
{% for i in result %}
    <tr>
        <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}0">{{i.0}}</td>
        <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}1">{{i.1}}</td>
        <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}2">{{i.2}}</td>
        <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}3">{{i.3}}</td>
        <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}4">CELL TO INSERT END TIME*</td>
        <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}5">{{i.5}}</td>
        <td id="tdId_{{ i.0 }}6">{{i.6}}</td>
        <td><button value="{{i.0}}" type="button" onclick="setEndActivity(this.value)">End</button><td/>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

ulrs.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'your_app_name'

urlpatterns = [
        'ending/',
        views.ending, 
        name='ending'),
    path(
        'ending/ajax/end-activity/',
        views.ajax_ending, 
        name='ajax_ending'),
    path(
        'ending/ajax/load-results/',
        views.ajax_load_results, 
        name='ajax_load_results'),
]
```

(Not tested, if throws a error let me know)

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I'm completely new to Ajax. Could you please clarify this `xhttpRequest.open("GET", "./ajax/load-results/", true)` and this `const request = new Request('./ajax/end-activity/',` and how to corresponding entries in `urls.py` will look like? and how to `ajax-ending.html` will look like? I should probably insert a link in `base.html` to register ajax?

Comment: Oh this is just the way i named in my project the urls, you don't need to write the ajax part but i think this helps in organization. The ajax-ending is just this code above, is just a copy of <tr></tr> part, this ajax-ending.html can be in the same directory as template.html. I will edit my anwser to add a urls.py example

Comment: And why here is always the value of `2` is it right? `dataToBackEnd.append("start_date", document.getElementById(`tdId_${i.id}2`).value)
        dataToBackEnd.append("start_time", document.getElementById(`tdId_${i.id}2`).value)
        dataToBackEnd.append("end_date", document.getElementById(`tdId_${i.id}2`).value)
        dataToBackEnd.append("end_time", document.getElementById(`tdId_${i.id}2`).value)`

Comment: Oh no, my mistake, this is the id from td which the information of table is, i edited but i don't saw the "end_date" td so i let the same as start_date

Comment: I'm sorry I completely don't know where to start debug and what could be wrong. I'm sending [forms.py](https://pastebin.com/yC802kR6), [views.py](https://pastebin.com/GWj01x4F), [urls.py](https://pastebin.com/WLS2FJAA), [ending.html](https://pastebin.com/H0nVEQEq) and [base3.html](https://pastebin.com/kKUiawM7)

Comment: No problem, the request are not reaching any urls i suppose, `path('ajax_ending/', ajax_ending, name = 'ajax_ending'),` should be `path('ending/ajax/end_activity/', ajax_ending, name = 'ajax_ending'),` because in the template the request is for `./ajax/end_activity/` you can change the request for `../ajax/end_activity/` if you want to keep your urls.py like this

Comment: OK, I fixed it. But it seems that `setEndActivity(activityId)` is not right. The user should be able to edit a cell in a row and set the end of the activity Then it should collect the data from the table row including the end of activity and call another stored procedure (go to database), insert the end and then reload a page with the same values in FromToForm, now the page should display logically one row less (because the end is already not NULL)

Comment: No problem, i edit my answer and put a input on the table and set the td id as the input id so it gets the input id, in this setEndActivity function the data is stored as a formData and send to the views as request.POST on views you verify if the data is valid through the form, save the end time in database and return a response with status=200, the setEndActivity read the response and calls the fuction to get the new body table, in the views you can make the same query to get the data as you did in your views, after that you just call the template of tbody and pass the context

Comment: Javascript writes this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at setEndActivity ((index):173)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):68)` when I click the End button.

Comment: I should probably write `i.0` instead of `i.id`. Could you please adjust the answer?

Comment: Now the problem is that I need to refer in `setEndActivity` to data from the form. I'm able to refer to data from the table rows now.

Comment: I see, i don't understand the way that results are stored and why you are using i.0, i thought that maybe the results comes with id but seems that you stored as 0 but no problem, i will edit my answer. To get the data from the form you can just get element by id because the form fields has unique ids, if you open the dev tools of your browser you can see their ids

Comment: Thank you. I'm learning ajax and understanding it a little already. Probably the method seEndActivity will have more parameters, taken from the table row. I'd like to refer to these data in a django view. I don't know how to do this. First, I need to update the database (insert the data with endtime) and then I'd like to refresh the table, which should not show the updated row in a database.

Comment: I it's a bit tricky in the start but you will get it fast. To refer this data in the view you can add form fields and access the data after form validation with form.cleaned_data[...], you can access the data with request.POST too but it's better for you to check if the data is valid with form. For update data you can get the data with activity parameter that we pass to the views in setEndActivity function

Comment: Here we have `const dataToBackEnd = new FormData()
        dataToBackEnd.append("activity", activityId)` I'd like to refer to this data in a view and then call a stored procedure with this data (for simplicity some update statement).

Comment: You can just do something like `req.POST['activity']` as django docs said, the request.POST is used to access the data from body, this is why we send the request.POST for forms to check the validation
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/

Comment: And should I call `if request.is_ajax()` first?

Comment: Well, i don't really know, i never used that but i guess it should be ok to use

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing [wrong](https://imgur.com/a/ufCla58). Here I should see `{{activity}}` in the template, or not?

Comment: No, this activity is simple the i.0, is the same value of activityId that is passed for setEndActivity function in template

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/Fxn4FUp) prints the console.log the right value 3, but how could I see this 3 in a view?

Comment: When you append a data to formdata the first argument is a string that is like a dict key in python, so in the views you can write `req.POST['activity']` or you can use pythion debugger and write `import pdb` / `pdb.set_trace()` and in your cmd that is running django `print(req.POST)` to inspect the req.POST object to see the data inside

Comment: in `ajax_ending(req)` shouldn't I pass context somewhere?

Comment: No because you will pass the context in the another view, ajax_load_results

Comment: I see why you had this doubt, in my anwser the ajax_ending was fetching data from database, but was a mistake, i edited

Comment: @xralf you don't need to create a form if you are using Ajax, just display the list of all records which have "finish time" as NULL and update the database via Ajax

Comment: @Luiz in `ajax_load_results`  name `from_to_form` is not defined.

Comment: @Luiz  If I write in `ajax_load_results` `start = request.GET['start_date']` this writes `KeyError`

Comment: @xralf I edit my anwser to pass the start_date, end_date, start_time and end_time through request so you can get in ajax_load_results and make the datetime object to make the db query, the `datetime.strptime` function depends of how you write dates so just edit if you don't write "dd-mm-yyyy"

Comment: but `start = request.GET['start_date']` gives `KeyError`

Comment: I edit the template.html to pass the start_date in url, after that still gives you a key error?

Comment: @Luiz Now, it makes sense. I believe I will manage it to finish it.

Comment: So, it works, but is it neccessary in `ajax_ending` this code? `from_to_form = FromToForm(req.POST)
        if from_to_form.is_valid():` we don't use data from from_to_form in this function.

Comment: If you don't use the start_date, start_time, end_date and end_time it's not necessary